# How to change the database connection to create an installer for a java application?

Tags: java, mysql

I have created a java application in netbeans with connection to a localhost Mysql database.

-----------------------------------Code of connection------------------------------------------

```
public static Connection getConexao()throws SQLException{
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/World","root", "root");
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new SQLException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I would like that my application has used on more than one computer, but as the database is taken as localhost, I'm not sure how to change this in order to make possible that is not used only on my computer.

Can anyone help me or give some tips, so you can solve my problem? 
Sorry for my English.

I do not know if I explained myself very well, but any doubt, do not hesitate to ask.

ps: Basically think qa solution will be to change the link database, but I'm not sure, not sure that will solve my problem. So I'm asking for help.

I apologize for the inconvenience.
Thank you all.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class with main method which takes the command line arguments for database connection settings

Accordinly your database settings will be changed and you will be able to connect to any MySQL

you can get the input from keyboard and pass those values to get the database connection

```
    package in.sblog.db;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ReadDBSettings {

  /**
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String connectionURL = null;
    String username = null;
    String password = null;

    try {
      System.out.print("Enter your DB connection URL: ");
      connectionURL = br.readLine();
      System.out.print("Enter your DB username: ");
      username = br.readLine();
      System.out.print("Enter your DB password: ");
      password = br.readLine();
      System.out.println("connectonURL:" + connectionURL + ", username:" + username + ", password:" + password);
      try {
        Connection conn = getConexao(connectionURL, username, password);
        //do your code
      } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      ioe.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    }
  }

  public static Connection getConexao(String connectionURL, String username, String password) throws SQLException {
    try {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + connectionURL, username, password);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      throw new SQLException(e.getMessage());
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
Could you be more explicit in your explanation? 
Or give a small practical example? Because I'm new to java and dont quite understand what I have to do. I apologize.

Comment: check it now if it suits your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you need are dynamic values for:

- Database Host/Name
- User
- Password

You can change the methode, so that it takes those values as parameters and builds the connection string:

```
public static Connection getConnection(String host, String user, String pwd)
{
        String dbHost = "jdbc:mysql://" + host;   //needs checking etc, error handling
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        return DriverManager.getConnection(dbHost, user, pwd);
}
```

Where you get this values from does not matter. You could read them from a config file (properties), from the command line or make some sort of GUI where the user can enter the values.

Example for reading parameters from the command line. When you start your program just add the three values seperated by space after the program name.
For example if you have your program in a jar-file:

```
java -jar MyDatabaseTest.jar localhost/World root rootPwd
```

Then in your main methode read those values:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   //first check length/null of args etc.
   String host = args[0];
   String user = args[1];
   String pwd = args[2];

   Connection con = YourDatabaseClass.getConnection(host, user, pwd);
}
```